# R Keras predict_prob for multi input model is not working. I can train the model sucessfuly but while scoring I get error

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

The multi-input model that takes as input 2 list text embedding and structured features and generate class probabilities. I can train the model successfully but during predict_prob I get an error

```
 categorical_input <- layer_input(shape = c(3116),

                                 dtype = "float32",

                                 name = "categorical_input")

categorical_layer <- categorical_input %>%

  layer_dense(units = 803,

              activation = "relu",

              name = "categorical_layer")


main_input <-

  layer_input(shape = c(26),

              dtype = 'int32',

              name = 'main_input')

text_input <- main_input %>%

  layer_embedding(input_dim = 48297, output_dim = 100) %>%

  layer_gru(units = 100,

            dropout = 0.2,

            recurrent_dropout = 0.2)



main_output <-

  layer_concatenate(c(text_input, categorical_layer)) %>%

  layer_dense(units = 803,

              activation = 'softmax',

              name = 'main_output')



##

model <- keras_model(list(main_input, categorical_input), main_output)

##
optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr=0.001)
model %>% compile(

  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",

  metrics = c(top_5_categorical_accuracy = metric_top_5_categorical_accuracy,

              "accuracy"),

  optimizer = optimizer



)
```

When I try to generate a prediction based on input structured features(one_hot_encode_test) and text (train tokens)

```
str(one_hot_encode_test)
Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  ..@ i       : int [1:36] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ p       : int [1:3117] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 1 3116
  ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr "1"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3116] "veh_eng_db_cd101-10A" "veh_eng_db_cd101-10B" "veh_eng_db_cd101-10C" "veh_eng_db_cd101-10D" ...
  ..@ x       : num [1:36] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..@ factors : list()

text :- str(train_tokens)
 num [1, 1:26] 13 28 4 36 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...





input = matrix(unlist(L), ncol = 3142, byrow = TRUE)
input = do.call(rbind,lapply(L,matrix,ncol=3142,byrow=TRUE))
#
predict_vmrs33 = model %>% predict_proba(input, batch_size = 1, verbose = 1)
```

I get error
"Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'predict_proba"

Answer (score 0):

The only change I MADE - uSE predict function instead of predict_prob and instead of creating a matrix on the two input I created a list(train_tokens,one_hot_encode_test)

predict = model %>% predict(list(train_tokens,one_hot_encode_test), batch_size = 1, verbose = 1)

This link helped me arrived at this solution https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/examples/quora_siamese_lstm.html